# How to remove X files in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, rm

How would I do the following command? This is the following pseudocode I have:

```
ls -U | head -4 < rm *
```

I want to delete the below four files

```
ubuntu@ip:/tmp$ ls -U | head -4
c9e5aff2-f4f6-459e-9752-466625165fa0.jpg
815626f8-2650-4596-94b9-796a82780390.jpg
b9259a6b-b421-4b64-ba4d-72fd632703a3.jpg
78c243e7-43df-417d-9dcf-a4578f1c1f20.jpg
```

Comment: that'll never work. that would redirect the output of `rm` as input to `head`. `ls|head -4|xargs rm` xargs takes its stdin and turns it into command line args for the specified command.

Comment: `ls -U` lists files in directory order, which is essentially arbitrary. Are you sure that's the criterion you want to use?

Comment: Note that both current answers can fail if any of the file names contain spaces or certain other special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) should do the trick:

```
$ ls -U | head -4 | xargs rm
```

Comment: Though both solutions listed thus far work, this is the superior solution as xargs will stream the output of the prior command into the input of the next

Comment: @AmirAfghani Indeed. My answer isn't meant to compete on the performance of the computer, but as a time-saver if your memory is as bad as mine. Writing a for loop is often faster than getting on StackOverflow and figuring out how to _really_ do it. :P

Answer (score 2):

If you can't remember bash syntax a simple `for` loop often works like a charm:

```
for file in `ls -U | head -4`; do rm $file; done
```